# @fontawesome-svg-core Requiring Authentication

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

I am trying to install Fontawesome 5 in a create-react-app project. I have a Pro license. It won't install @fontawesome-svg-core (or any other @fortawesome module). It says it requires authentication. I have an .npmrc file sitting next to my package.json file. Tried npm and yarn: `yarn add @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core` and `npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core`, same results Anyone seen this before?

.npmrc file:

```html
@fortawesome:registry=https://npm.fontawesome.com/
//npm.fontawesome.com/:_authToken=########-####-####-####-##############
```

error:

```html
Error: https://npm.fontawesome.com/@fortawesome%2ffontawesome-svg-core: authentication required
      at Request.params.callback [as _callback] (C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\lib\cli.js:66056:18)
      at Request.self.callback (C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\lib\cli.js:140665:22)
      at Request.emit (events.js:314:20)
      at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\lib\cli.js:141637:10)
      at Request.emit (events.js:314:20)
      at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\lib\cli.js:141559:12)
      at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:420:28)
      at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:326:22)
      at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1252:12)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
```

Answer (score 1):

They cut off our access from the authenticated NPM, thinking somehow that this would make us more willing to pay for FA6... go figure...

Anyway.

You can get the fontawesome-svg-core directory and the other free packages from their Github repo https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/tree/master/js-packages/%40fortawesome

You can get the remaining from packages from your download page on the font awesome website: look for the npm packages.

Then you'll need to put that all together somewhere you can import from. Here it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Opening my .npmrc file and removing any font-awesome references worked for me.